# .includes method is always true in js

Tags: javascript, html, include

I have this little code to make a login with a key that needs to includes variuous strings... but the .includes method is always true can someone explain me what's wrong?

```
function validate() {
var keyInput = document.getElementById("keyInputBox").value;
console.log('User trying to log with key: "' + keyInput + '"');
var keyRequireBoolean0 = keyInput.includes('anon')
if (keyRequireBoolean0 = true) {
    var keyRequireBoolean1 = keyInput.includes('sup')
    if (keyRequireBoolean1 = true) {
        alert('login successfull ' + keyRequireBoolean0)
    } else {
        alert('Invaild Key');
    }
} else {
    alert('Invaild Key');
}}
```

and this is the html part:

```
  <input type="password" id="keyInputBox" placeholder="Key">
  <input type="submit" onclick="validate()" value="Check">
```

Comment: `keyRequireBoolean0 = true` _sets_ it to _true_, use `==` to compare instead.

Comment: UHHHHHHH yeah I forgot to add another =

Comment: You don't need any of them, just do `if(keyRequireBoolean0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is compare the boolean:

```
function validate() {
var keyInput = document.getElementById("keyInputBox").value;
console.log('User trying to log with key: "' + keyInput + '"');
var keyRequireBoolean0 = keyInput.includes('anon')
if (keyRequireBoolean0 === true) {
    var keyRequireBoolean1 = keyInput.includes('sup')
    if (keyRequireBoolean1 === true) {
        alert('login successfull ' + keyRequireBoolean0)
    } else {
        alert('Invaild Key');
    }
} else {
    alert('Invaild Key');
}}
```